# Storing data created in a loop in global environment?

Tags: loops, dataframe, environment

I am very new to R, and I have a larger dataframe with 58 observations that I want to break up in 29 dataframes, consisting of column 1&2, 3&4, etc.

I tried the following

```
for (i in 1:29){
 x <- LCMS[,((i*2)-1):(i*2)]
 assign("dfi",x,envir=globalenv())
 }
```

, and do not receive an error message, but nothing is saved but "dfi", which is then the dataframe from the last iteration.

I guess the problem that "dfi" is entered as a name, so it is not used for the iteration process? But how do I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, assign will save the object to an environment, not as a file in your computer. To write files in your computer, you could use the "write" functions (csv, xlsx, there's a function for whatever format you want).

Second, "dfi" is not changing because i is inside quotation marks, making it part of the "dfi" character string, not a numeric object. If you want to create files called df1,df2,df3, etc., you need to use the function "paste".

I have written some code as an example, hope it helps!

```
    for(i in 1:29) {
       new.data <- LCMS[,((i*2)-1):(i*2)]
       df.name <- paste("LCMS_pair",i,".xlsx",sep = "") 
       write.xlsx(new.data,df.name,row.names = F) }
```